# Bar chart. I need to read data from file and columns will be axes or 3 dimension is needed to explain the data/

Tags: python-3.x

I can draw bar chart by using two columns from a csv file. But I need:
1- Forexample there are 2 rows for Il column. Il=Adiyaman has 2 rows. I should sum up them, take care Adiyaman as one row and addition value should be used while making bar chart. I tried groupby code but it does not work.
2- I want to draw a bar chart for example: x,y,z columns will be shown in the bar chart with different colours. To compare these 3 columns, I want to see in a one chart.

```py
g_votes=votes.groupby('Il')
g_votes.plot.bar('Il','MUHARREM_INCE',rot=1)

import pandas as pnd
votes=pnd.read_csv("/Users/my/Documents/Adana_Amasra_2018.csv")
votes.head(3)
```

```
Il  Il_Ilce_Merkez  Belde_Koy   Sandık sayısı   Kayıtlı seçmen sayısı   Oy kullanan seçmen sayısı   Geçerli oy  MUHARREM INCE   MERAL AKŞENER   RECEP TAYYİP ERDOĞAN    SELAHATTİN DEMİRTAŞ TEMEL KARAMOLLAOĞLU DOĞU PERİNÇEK
0   Adana   1   0   4543    1524922 1313501 1285873 460752  125894  567605  119498  9799    2325
1   Adiyaman    1   0   759 263304  227066  221105  45816   8557    147184  16124   3081    343
2   Adiyaman    0   1   684 135977  118280  115549  23036   2935    79742   8825    825 186
```

```
votes.plot.bar('Il','MUHARREM INCE')
```

There is no error message, it does not result as I want.

Answer (score 0):

you should use matplotlib to create the graph that you require, Im not sure exactly what you want as the question is hard to understand but this creates graphs with relative ease.

[Here](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/) is the link to some documentation that I have found helpful, all that is needed to create a graph is two lines of code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
```

This will create a simple line graph, to create a bar chart you need to make subplots, as is outlined in the documentation.

[image: Here is an example]

I hope that I've helped you create what you are after, enjoy.

Comment: But I need to take data from a file: x,y columns and rectangle bars -> all these data should be taken from columns in a file. And I need to sum up all the other columns values in each according to one column. For example: column1,column2,column3,column4
a, 1,2,0
a,1,1,4
Firstly I need to have a data as below
column1,column2,column3
a, 2,3,4

Comment: But I need to take data from a file. For example: column1,column2,column3,column4
a, 1,2,0
a,1,1,4
Firstly I need to have a data as below
column1,column2,column3,column4
a, 2,3,4
Then column1=x,column2,column3 and column4 will be rectangulars in the figure, and their values will be y axis.

Comment: to take data from a file just set a variable (I'll use x). After that, just type x = votes[:,0] and that will give you your first column, then repeat this step until you have all desired aspects of csv file.

Comment: Is that more of what you are after? - Also if it is please can you upvote my answer so that I may receive more attention when asking my own questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the answer of my question. Perhaps I could not ask clearly.
Can we go step by step?For example: column1,column2,column3,column4 
a, 1,2,0 
a,1,1,4 
Firstly I need to have a data as below (grouping according to column1 values and having only one row.
column1,column2,column3,column4 
a, 2,3,4

Comment: Will you help me about my question?

Comment: Are you just trying to separate your data into different variables? and yes I can, do you just want to email me? so you can make it very detailed? My email is tobsterclark@gmail.com